# How to remove spaces ( new lines) from string?

Tags: php, preg-replace

my string is:

```
$str = "[php] 

complete
once
A lot of text and other staffs!
but

[/php]";

$str = preg_replace("/\[php\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/php]/is","<pre>\\1</pre>",$str);

echo $str;
```

on out:

```
<pre>complete
once
A lot of text and other staffs!
but</pre>
```

It works in a sandbox [test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee92ee953782281d936b35a40c90ccdd154082c4), but on my site I have a space ( new line ) in the end of the text:

[image: test1 without U]

interesting, that if I'll use the "U" modificator than the space ( new line ) will be on the top of the text:

[image: test2 with U]

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[php\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/php]/Uis","<pre>\\1</pre>",$str);
```

screen of textarea:

[image: in the textarea]

**update** a very basic page for this ( example ), u can just put the [php] bbcode in textarea on form and submit it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style>
.code {
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$str = $_POST['textarea'];
$content = preg_replace("/\[php\]\s*(.*)\s*\[\/php\]/si","<pre class='code'>\\1</pre>",$str);
echo $content;
?>
<form method="post" action="" class="contactform">
<textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="met_button pull-right" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see the spaces on a bottom or top.

Comment: What is the input, current output and expected output?

Comment: well, input can be different for example: `$input_str = "test, test test, [php] my php code [/php] test test, test";` on `$output = "test, test test, <pre>my php code</pre> test test, test";` look, I don't need a spaces in the `pre` tag only. Other string text must be as is.

Comment: I'm asking you to clarify. If you can't clarify (or don't want to) I can't give you a solution.

Comment: this is kinda bit of bbcode, I want that `[php]` and a code inside was replaced by `pre` tag.

Comment: I know, but you haven't made it clear what you want to do with the newlines. Give some sample input and output.

Comment: Input it's my string, here is the sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15495423a7789709642c0fae75dfad00c08b5b08 working well as u can see, but the same code on my site isn't working so. Watch the screens.

Comment: Do you have an extra newline in your source or something? Anything inside a `<textarea>` is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: I've add screen of textarea. No matter how many lines on top or in a bottom of the text, they must be removed ( thats what I want ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$str = "[php]       

complete
once
A lot of text and other staffs!
but


[/php]";

$arr = array('[php]','[/php]');

$string = str_replace($arr,'', $str);
echo $string ;
```

Output:

```
complete
once
A lot of text and other staffs!
but
```

Comment: I dont need all string, only in the `pre` tag.

Comment: I'm not removing tags, just making [php] bbcode to `pre` tag.